# Storing multiple matches during iteration in java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I'm trying to figure the following problem out in the scenario.

My method takes an `ArrayList` of user input, I also have a `HashMap<String(keyword), ArrayList<String>(collection of responses)>` in a separate class.

What I need is to match the user input against the HashMap's keywords and store the respective ArrayLists (returned from the HashMap key) for further manipulation.

The problem is that after one match I am not sure how to continue, as I'm going through user input with `for-each loop.` After the first match, I need to continue looking for a second, third and so on.

For each HashMap key match, I need to store the appropriate ArrayList - so I think it should look like this:

```
ArrayList<String> match1 = hashMap.get(wordFromInput);
ArrayList<String> match2 = hashMap.get(wordFromInput2);
```

To me, this seems like it should have an easy/obvious solution, but I haven't been able to find it yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: A list of lists?

Comment: @m0skit0 do you mean to add each ArrayList match to an overall ArrayList during the iteration?

Comment: Yes, `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`.

Comment: I did have this as an idea, but afterwards, I will need to work with each collection element. I tried to find how to break them down into separate ArrayList (if I add them to a big one), but failed. Suggestions on a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish the task at hand by creating a stream of the HashMap's entrySet then 
 **[filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-)**, **[map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)** and **[collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-)** the result into a list.

```
List<ArrayList<String>> resultSet = hashMap.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(e -> inputArrayList.contains(e.getKey()))
                        .map(Entry::getValue)
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

using the imperative approach:

```
List<ArrayList<String>> resultSet = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : hashMap.entrySet())
{
      if(inputArrayList.contains(entry.getKey())){
           resultSet.add(entry.getValue());
      }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help and sorry to be silly, but I am not 100% sure how to implement this. could you possibly elaborate/add comments?

Comment: @Codingnooby inside "_My method takes an ArrayList of user input_ " Assuming the method parameter is called `inputArrayList` and you have retrieved the `HashMap` instance with the identifier `hashMap` to reference that instance then you can simply past this code with the method and it should do the job.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, Aomine, but for some reason, it doesn't compile and I'm not sure why. To be honest, I understand the logic behind your method, but it uses concepts in Java that I have not been introduced to yet and I can't say I can comfortably use it. If  I am understanding it correctly, however, the resultSet is a List with ArrayList elements? Thank you a lot for the answer though.

Comment: @Codingnooby see edit. I have included an imperative approach which you'll be more familiar with and yes resultSet is a List of ArrayList elements.

Comment: thank you so much, this looks great! can you also help out (point me to a method) with extracting and storing each ArrayList from resultSet List, as I need to use those individually after I have matched them? I already tried searching for this with no result. thanks again, really appreciate the help!

Comment: whenever you need to perform some logic on the ArrayLists within resultSet  simply loop over the resultSet. there is no need to manually store each list into its own variable... you could accomplish that with something like `for (ArrayList<String> list : resultSet) { /* do something with list */ };`

Comment: Also, it's not possible to store _each and every ArrayList_ within its own variable because you won't know at compile time how many ArrayLists resultSet will contain.

Comment: I agree, it's quite obvious, but only realised it when you pointed it out. Thank you very much for your help, I think your code works fine, but unfortunately, there is something else wrong with my class so I am getting exceptions. Still trying to work that out :) Thanks again for all the help!